# Is it possible to use LinqPad with an ASP.NET Website (Rather than a Web Application)?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, linqpad

I'm very interested in testing out LinqPad with our Entity Framework 4.0 based websites, but when I load up LinqPad it wants me to attach it to an assembly (dll or exe). The ASP.NET applications we are building are using the 'Website' template (App_Code folder, etc.) that is not deployed as a compiled DLL. I realize that if the project type were 'ASP.NET Web Application' I would have access to the DLL, but unfortunately this is out of my control.

Is it in any way possible for me to use LinqPad in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest moving Entity classes to a separate assembly. This will not just solve your problem, but also is the right thing to do from design standpoint.

Also, you could convert your web site to web application.

[Update]

If you cannot split entities to a separate assembly, and if converting to web application is not feasible, you could try extracting compiled dll from web site.
When your site is built the dll will be located at path like this (depends on your platform):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website1
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm going give this a go and see if your update does the trick. Sadly I cannot split to a separate assembly or convert the project without jumping through many hoops for a personal interest.